# Importing raster data with known lat/lon to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I have a number of raster files with known latitude/longitude of the picture edges.

What is the appropriate way to import such pictures in QGIS with correct coordinates?

All the options that I can find in QGIS raster transformation require me to input some other coordinates than lat/lon, and I am not sure how to calculate them; and the georeferencer plugin requires me to match points that I am unable to enter - the picture edges are transparent and not visible in the georeference tool, and the pictures don't contain obvious landmarks, I have to proceed from the lat/lon ranges supplied in metadata.

Answer (score 2):

How about this, using QGIS gereferencer:

1. Create point with ANY source X,Y and ANY lat/long.
2. Edit this point manually in GCP table entering needed values for pixel coordinates. You don't have to see the edge, just enter values you need, like 0,0 or image width in pixels, -image height in pixels, etc, this will be your edge. Enter referenced LAT/LON deduced from metadata.
3. Repeat as many times as your transformation of choice requires.

Note that you can have points even outside the image.